# What is the better way to read data from multiple Event Hubs in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

I'm looking for a better solution on how to read multiple event hubs that are in the same Event Hubs Namespace.

If you have one event hub in your namespace you can use [Azure Event Hubs connter for Spark](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark) and use this pySpark code to read the data:

```
# create a connection string to input events:

ev_namespace    ="{your_namespace_name}"
ev_name         ="{your_eventhub_name}"
ev_sas_key_name ="{your_key_name}"
ev_sas_key_val  = "{your_key_value}"
conn_string="Endpoint=sb://{0}.servicebus.windows.net/;EntityPath={1};SharedAccessKeyName={2};SharedAccessKey={3}".format(ev_namespace, ev_name, ev_sas_key_name, ev_sas_key_val) 

ehConf = {}
ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(conn_string)
ehConf['eventhubs.consumerGroup'] = "eventparket-cg"

# read dataframe
df = (spark.readStream 
                 .format("eventhubs") 
                 .options(**ehConf) 
                 .load()
            )
```

But what if you have more than one eventHub in the same namespace?

```
ev_name         ="{your_eventhub_name_1}"
ev_name         ="{your_eventhub_name_2}"
...
ev_name         ="{your_eventhub_name_7}"
```

In my case: I use Databricks and I have several eventHubs with the same schema in Event Hubs Namespace, which I need to read in one stream.

Can I read several or all of the event hubs at once?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your code to accept CLI arguments to `spark-submit` as `sys.argv` options, then you can grab the `ev_name` from there, or a config file, and deploy more than one instance of your application.

Otherwise, as with any Python application, you cannot have two values for the same variable.